# Why would my site be redirecting to /downloader/?

Tags: magento-1.7, downloader, local

I'm working on a local development server using MAMP, and it's version controlled using .git & Tower. I went to begin working on a new feature, and did a fresh pull from our master branch as per usual. Now when I navigate to any page, I'm redirected to /downloader/. I did my research before posting the topic, and here's what I've checked so far:

- local.xml settings all point to the appropriate dB & user settings
- local.xml and Mage.php exist and are set to 644 permissions
- var/cache & car/session directories have been cleared

Any other ideas of what I should be looking for to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start debugging from index.php, where you'll find following codes

```
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
$maintenanceFile = 'maintenance.flag';

if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    if (is_dir('downloader')) {
        header("Location: downloader");
    } else {
        echo $mageFilename." was not found";
    }
    exit;
}
```

So, all the conditions are fulfilled perfectly or not.

Comment: As suspected, Mage.php wasn't able to be found. Previously I had checked permissions on Mage.php, but they were fine. The actual problem was the permissions on the /app/ folder. Thanks.